# Compiling a Gradle Java project with Java 8 but running tests with Java 11

Tags: java, gradle, java-11, openjdk-11

As the first part of a transition process of my projects, I would like to keep compile with JDK-8 compiler, but execute tests with JDK-11 runtime.

My projects are Gradle projects (6.+ if it matters), using the `java` plugin or `java-library` plugins.

I could not find a way to do it with Gradle options.

I tried to compile (`gradlew build`) in one terminal with JDK-8, and then switch to another terminal with JDK 11 and run the tests (`gradlew test`), but it re-compiled the code.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Are you doing this because the application will be running only in a Java8 environment?

Comment: I'm doing this because I want to do the migration gradually, and reduce risks. This step, as I read in many places, is very common. I'm surprised that it's not trivial to do it with Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure all Java-related tasks (compilations, tests, JavaExec, JavaDoc, etc) with a different JDK than what is used to run Gradle. There is a chapter in the [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#example_configure_java_7_build) that gives an example of how to run Gradle with Java 8 but use Java 7 in all tasks. It works the same with Java 11.

For your project, you can continue running Gradle with Java 8 but add the following for running tests with a different version:

```
// Gradle <= 6.6 (Groovy DSL)
tasks.withType(Test) {
    executable = new File("/my/path/to/jdk11/bin/java")
}
```

The user guide has a more configurable solution, but this is the gist of it.

A cool feature that is part of the upcoming version 6.7 of Gradle is support for JVM toolchains. As it is now, you have to download a JDK 11 distribution yourself and configure the path to it. Newer versions will allow you to declare the version and let Gradle download it for you (from AdoptOpenJDK) if missing:

```
// Gradle >= 6.7 (Groovy DSL)
// Unreleased at the time of this writing and the syntax is therefore subject to change
test {
    javaLauncher = javaToolchains.launcherFor {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}
```

A final option is to run Gradle with Java 11 and make the compiler target Java 8 using the `release` option:

```
// Run Gradle with Java 11
compileJava {
    options.release = 8
}
```